# Typescript function array type check

Tags: typescript

The  code is simple

```
// it is ok because type 'string' is assignable to type 'string | number'

const arr:Array<string|number> = []

arr.push('foo')
```

But I got error with the following code.

```
interface Fn<T> {
  (val: T): T
}


const fnArr:Fn<string|number>[] = []


const fn = (str:string)=>str

//error
fnArr.push(fn)
```

and the error shows:

```
 Argument of type '(str: string) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Fn<string | number>'.
 Types of parameters 'str' and 'val' are incompatible.
 Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
 Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2345)
```

the logic seems to be opposite. the fnArr is declared as an array whose elements are functions with string or number parameters, so it is valid to push a function with string parameter.I **thought** `'string' is assignable to type 'string | number'`, but why the error shows `Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

what is the rules when TS process array element type checking?  assign element type to declared array type or assign declared array type to the element type?

**Edit:**

After read [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions) mentioned by @Aleksey, I still feel a little confused.
I mean, the function

`(val: string | number) => string | number`

has parameter `val` with type `string` or type `number`, I thought it has a larger scale than the function only has paramter with type `string`. just like an analogy. I thought type `number` extends  type`number | string`. so I thought there shouldn't be any error with code above

In the contrary, as @Aleksey said, the function

```
(val: string | number) => string | number
```

can handle arguments of type number and type string, but the function `(val: string) => string` can't handle arguments of type `number`, I think he is correct.

so I still feel confused.

Comment: Assign element type to declared array type. See explanation below why this is not working

Comment: Imaging that `const fn = (str: string) => str.endsWith('test') : str : ''` . Now if assignment would be allowed, you could do `fnArr[0](123)` which will cause runtime error because number doesn't have `endsWith` method

Comment: thank you @Aleksey.  BTW the articele might help.https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the actual question here is why

```
(val: string) => string
```

is not assignable to

```
(val: string | number) => string | number
```

That's because the former can't handle arguments of type `number`

> To check if `x` is assignable to `y`, we first look at the parameter list. Each parameter in `x` must have a corresponding parameter in `y` with a compatible type.

More info on function types compatibility [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions).

---

So one possible solution would be declaring array that that can accept functions  of type
`(val: string) => string` or functions of type `(val: number) => number`

```
const fnArr: (Fn<string> | Fn<number>)[] = []

const fn = (str: string) => str

fnArr.push(fn) // is ok now
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdgHgCoD4oF4oAoBuBDAGwC4okBKDNJAbgChaBjAezgGdgoAzOAQQCc%20JLPATs%20ASzgBzNAB9YiOAFcAtgCMIfFGQDaAXQxR99Zmw7dDWMSTGSpFdGjH1u-PgDowS1gAss3CgB6QKhxVigmAGsoOCYAd1ogA)